# DART SQL How do I read multiple row values (with multiple columns) from SQL query results in Dart?

Tags: sql, dart

Right now i am able to read data from the column in the single returned row ad below

```
    var resultsDoc = await conn
      .query('select fNAME, SPECIALITY, CATENAME from doctor where id = ?', [5]);
  for (var rowDoc in resultsDoc) {    
      ffname = rowDoc[0];      //reading value at column 1
      sspeciality = rowDoc[1];         //reading value at column 2
      ccategory = rowDoc[2];    //reading value at column 3
  }
```

what if i wanted to return the entire table as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ8GP.png)

Team, assist on how to read those values.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You were close!

```
for (var rowDoc in resultsDoc) {
  print(rowDoc.join('\t'));    
}
```

Or did you want to transpose the list of lists, so that you'd have 3 lists, one for each column?

Comment: `var sampleresult = await conn
             .query('SELECT * FROM doctor');
  for (var rowsample in sampleresult) {
    print(rowsample.join('\t'));
      }`  print the taable as i desired. How would i 'specify' that i need row 3 without using a where clause in the query.